# How to remove outliers by columns in R

Tags: r, outliers, standard-deviation

I have this data frame.

| IQ | sleep | GRE | happiness |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | 70 | 200 | 15 |
| 40 | 50 | 150 | 15 |
| 70 | 20 | 70 | 10 |
| 150 | 150 | 80 | 6 |
| 148 | 60 | 900 | 7 |
| 115 | 10 | 1200 | 40 |
| 110 | 90 | 15 | 5 |
| 120 | 40 | 60 | 12 |
| 99 | 30 | 70 | 15 |
| 1000 | 15 | 30 | 68 |
| 70 | 60 | 12 | 70 |

I would like to remove the outliers for each variable. I do not want to delete a whole row if one value is identified an outlier. For example, let's say the outlier for IQ is 40, I just want to delete 40, I don't want a whole row deleted.

If I define any values that are > mean * 3sd and < mean - 3sd as outliers, what are the codes I can use to run it?
**If I can achieve this using Dplyr and subset, that would be great**

I would expect something like this

| IQ | sleep | GRE | happiness |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | 70 | 200 | 15 |
|  | 50 | 150 | 15 |
| 70 | 20 | 70 | 10 |
| 150 |  | 80 | 6 |
| 148 | 60 | 900 | 7 |
| 115 |  | 40 |  |
| 110 | 90 |  | 5 |
| 120 | 40 | 60 | 12 |
| 99 | 30 | 70 | 15 |
|  | 15 | 30 | 68 |
| 70 | 60 | 12 | 70 |

I have tried the remove_sd_outlier code (from dataPreperation package) and it deleted an entire row of data. I do not want this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scale()` to compute z-scores and `across()` to apply across all numeric variables. Note none of your example values are > 3 SD from the mean, so I used 2 SD as the threshold for demonstration.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(
    where(is.numeric),
    ~ ifelse(
      abs(as.numeric(scale(.x))) > 2,
      NA, 
      .x
    )
  ))
```

```
# A tibble: 11 × 4
      IQ sleep   GRE happiness
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1   105    70   200        15
 2    40    50   150        15
 3    70    20    70        10
 4   150    NA    80         6
 5   148    60   900         7
 6   115    10    NA        40
 7   110    90    15         5
 8   120    40    60        12
 9    99    30    70        15
10    NA    15    30        68
11    70    60    12        70
```

Comment: Question: for your code, why is it "(.x)' instead of (x)? If you don't mind, can you please explain the code for me? Sorry I am still very new to R

Comment: This is part of the anonymous function applied to each column by `across()`. You can specify the function(s) used by `across()` in multiple ways. I’ve used [purrr-style](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) function shorthand, where an anonymous function is written as a formula (e.g., `~ mean(.x) / 2`), and `.x` stands in for the passed value. You could instead use a base R anonymous function (e.g., `\(x) mean(x) / 2`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you could rephrase the nested ifelse() as case_when() for something easier to read, but hopefully this works for you.

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~ ifelse(. > (mean(.) + 3*sd(.)),
                         "",
                         ifelse(. < (mean(.) - 3*sd(.)),
                                "", 1*(.)))))
```

Comment: Using `""` will coerce the columns to character. Better to use `NA` for missing values.

Comment: Thank you <3 I like this way as well!

Comment: This approach could be adapted to quantile determination easily: `mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(. < (quantile(.,probs=0.25,na.rm=TRUE) - 1.5*IQR(.,na.rm=TRUE)),NA,ifelse(. > (quantile(.,probs=0.75,na.rm=TRUE) + 1.5*IQR(.,na.rm=TRUE)),NA,1*(.)))))`